# Chrome 84 'breaking' accordions and 'read more' buttons

Tags: google-chrome, accordion

It seems that Chrome 84 changed the way clicked links work for accordions/read more buttons.

For an example check https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/accordion/accordion.html in Safari and Chrome 84.

In Chrome 84 the clicked link just remains under the mouse pointer thus making accordions and 'hidden' texts with 'read more' buttons open in a wrong way.

I tried looking in the changelogs for any kind of attribute that can disable this behaviour, but couldn't find anything.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you describe. But my website had an issue with Chrome 84 and what I did is set below CSS and it solve my issue.

```
body {
  overflow-anchor: none;
}
```